# Which relationship should I choose in linq-to-sql?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce, one-to-many

I need to set a relation between classes:

First class is a `Route` . Route has `StartStation` (`Station` class), and `EndStation` (`Station` class).

And every station could be start or end station for many routes.

Is it `one-to-many` relation?

If yes, how can I set that relation?

Giving `EntitySet<Route>` on the `Station` class makes no sense for me, but maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that a single `Station` instance is reached by N `Route` instances, so the `Station`-`Route` relationship is one to many.

`StartStation` and `EndStation` would be roles that `Station` is playing in different routes. Each route has a start station and an end station, so the relationship would look something like this:

[image]

In such a way, I would advise that you set properties `StartStation` and `EndStation` as you just did, and having an `EntitySet<Route>` for each `Station` does actually make sense: is the collection of all routes that are related with that `Station` instance.

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself whether a Station can have more than one Routes. If this is the case then your relationship is many-to-many. If not then you should have a collection of Stations per each Route.